# Is the collection of all $2$x$2$ real matrices with both eigen values real dense in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Is $M$, the *collection of all $2$x$2$ real matrices with both eigen values real* dense in $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$? My answer NO.

Could some one verify my answer and answer the clarification too?

This is my approach. I claim that $\bar{M} \neq X$. Let A be any (fixed) matrix with a complex eigen value with non-zero imaginary part. I prove that no sequence in $M$ can approach $A$.

Let f : $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $tr(.)^2-4\cdot det(.)$. This is clearly a continuous function.

Suppose on the contrary, $\exists$ a sequence of matrices $A_n \in M$ such that $A_n \rightarrow A$ (wrt say, some matrix norm), then $f(A_n) \rightarrow f(A)$ (Let |f(A)| = r). That is, a sequence of non-negative real numbers approach a negative number, which is a contradiction because $B_{\frac{r}{2}}(f(A))$ contains no point of $f(A_n)$. Thus, $M$ is not dense in $X$.

Clarification:
1) Isn't $\bar{M} = M$ itself? (as $\bar{M} cannot contain a limit point outside M).

2) Do I need to be more specific about matrix norm for this answer, isn't existence enough?

Comment: Your approach also looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $M$ is the pre-image $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$, hence closed. So $M$ indeed coincides with its own closure.

The matrix norm does not matter, since they are all equivalent.